# Apache "connection reset" only after setting RewriteLogLevel to >0 on Win7

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I was working with mod_rewrite on my work computer, which runs apache 2.2 on XP.

More pertinently, I was using RewriteLogLevel 9 for debugging.
No problems.

I went home to do more work with apache 2.2 on Windows 7. The only change to the config was to add and set RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel.

After restarting apache, I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from chrome.

If I set RewriteLogLevel to 0, I get no error. Anything greater than 0 gets ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

I thought it might be permissions, but I checked against the config that I added:

```
RewriteLog "c:/wamp/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 1
```

c:/wamp/logs/rewrite.log is created, but nothing is written.

Error logs show nothing out of the ordinary.  Any ideas where else I might look for clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens with WampServer x64 on Windows 7.
It works correctly with WampServer x86.

Good luck

Comment: This is actually correct.  I never did understand the WHY, but you're the only answer so you get the check!